# Disable UITextField in UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I have a `UITextField` in a `UITableViewCell`.

Even though I set -

```
textField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
textField.enabled = NO
```

But when I click on the table cell which contains the textField, the keyboard comes up for the textfield.

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

EDIT: Strangely this is happening when I first set some text in the textfield. When the textfield is empty, it is not editable.

EDIT: Code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` -

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, cell.bounds.size.width - 20, cell.bounds.size.height - 20)];

textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
textField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

UIColor *placeholderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:146/255.0 green:146/255.0 blue:146/255.0 alpha:1];
textField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[self getPlaceHolderTextForIndexPath:indexPath] attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : placeholderColor}];
textField.keyboardType = [self getKeyboardTyeForIndexPath:indexPath];
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
textField.autocapitalizationType = [self getAutocapitaliztionTypeForIndexPath:indexPath];
textField.tag = 1;

if (_editingNotAllowed) {
    [textField setText:[self getTextForTextFieldWithIndexPath:indexPath]];
    [textField setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    textField.enabled = NO;
} else {
    [textField setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}        
[cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
```

Comment: Where are you setting those values? What method?

Comment: When making the table cells. In the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: If you dont want it to be editable why dont you use a label instead?

Comment: It is editable when the table first renders. The user fills that up, presses a button and then some more table cells are rendered and the old ones has to be present with the text the user entered before but it must not be editable further.

Comment: You need to show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: Have added the code for the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: NSLog out the value of _editingNotAllowed

Comment: The value for `_editingNotAllowed` is correct. I breakpointed and the control does come inside the `if`

Comment: `cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` seems to do the trick. Don't know why.

Comment: Whenever the table view ask for a cell you are creating a new text field and add it to the cell. So if the table view have many rows it creates a new text field whenever the cell becomes visible over and over again. Please fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create an UITableViewCell as shown in this repo :)

https://github.com/breeno/EditingUITableView

And use your custom UITableViewCell like this:

```
if(condition){ // Check the row must be TextField
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: nil];
    if(!cell){
         cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: nil];
    }
    cell.label.text = @"Title Row"; //UITextLabel Title
    UIColor *placeholderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:146/255.0 green:146/255.0 blue:146/255.0 alpha:1];
    cell.textField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[self getPlaceHolderTextForIndexPath:indexPath] attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : placeholderColor}];
    cell.textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    cell.textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    cell.textField.tag = 1;
} else { // Normal UITableViewCell 
}
```